# How to create Student in Django admin, if Student is a class, inherited from User and has required fields

Tags: django, inheritance

I am using Django, and i have two models, Student and Teacher, inherited from User. Each of them have User fields (login/password/group and so on), but User has one OneToOne field, Student_Group, where you can select Group for that student (not Django group, but group in University, something like MZ103, MZ203, MZ303...).

It creates correctly, but then, when i creating Student in admin page, Django (as usual, for all Users) asks only for username/password. I enter it, and then it SAVES all data, THEN you can change something - group, permissions, student_group, all you want.

For ordinary users it is okay, all fields become blank, and you can change them. But for Student model, Django tries to save it with Student_Group = null, and shows, that "Error, foreign key can't be null"

So, how can i ask django to fill all the fields, and then save (not just username/password)? Or how else can i create OneToOne reference in class, inherited from User?

Comment: It will be helpful to answer if you also share your code here.

Comment: Unfortunately i can't do this right now, but i can add it today's evening

Answer (score 0):

You can use `commit=False` to add code before saving.  So for the Student example:

```
# Create a form instance with POST data.
>>> f = AuthorForm(request.POST)

# Create, but don't save the new author instance.
>>> new_author = f.save(commit=False)

# Modify the author in some way.
>>> new_author.some_field = 'some_value'

# Save the new instance.
>>> new_author.save()
```